# What is the Kubernetes ApiServer endpoint to upload any YAML file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

As you probably know, Kubernetes Dashboard let the user to upload any YAML file to the API Server.

I browsed the API by Swagger UI but i cannot find any Api Server endpoint where to PUT/POST/DELETE a generic (and potentially multi-resource) Kubernetes YAML file, as the dashboard does.

In other words, I need the Api Server endpoint used by kubectl when the command is
`kubectl create -f myResources.yaml`

Answer (score 2):

No such endpoint exists. Adding `--v=6` to the kubectl command reveals the API calls it is making, and it iterates and posts individual objects